# Can we simply $L[n] = n + \tau(n-1) + 2\tau(n-2) + ... + (n-2)\tau(2)+(n-1)\tau(1)$ (makes $L[n]$ more easy to calculate)

Tags: number-theory

Can we simply $L[n]$ more?

$L[n] = n + \tau(n-1) + 2\tau(n-2) + ... + (n-2)\tau(2)+(n-1)\tau(1)$ where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of n.
In addition, $\tau(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} d^0 = \sum\limits_{d|n} 1$
So, $L[n] = n + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i)\tau(i)$
$= n + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j|i}(n-i)$
$= n + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j|i, i <n}(n-i)$
$= n + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\bigg(\sum\limits_{j|i, i <n}n - \sum\limits_{j|i, i <n}i\bigg)$

There are $\big\lfloor \frac{n}{j} \big\rfloor$ positive integers is divisibled by j and not exceed n ($\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$)

$L[n]= n + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\bigg(\sum\limits_{j|i, i <n}n - \sum\limits_{j|i, i <n}i\bigg)$

$= n + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\bigg(\sum\limits_{j|i, i <n}n - \sum\limits_{j|i, i <n}i\bigg)$

$= n + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\bigg(n\big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{j} \big\rfloor - \frac{j\big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{j} \big\rfloor \big(\big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{j} \big\rfloor + 1\big)}{2}\bigg)$

$= n + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{j} \big\rfloor\bigg(2n - j\big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{j} \big\rfloor -j\bigg)$

Comment: $L(n)$ is the sequence https://oeis.org/A051336 which does not give any much simpler relation. So apparently an algorithm using a single sum is as simple as it gets.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar Do you know what the O(sqrt(n)) algorithm to to generate $L(n)$ is, I can't see in that link.